# conditional ranking

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, rank

I'm trying to rank accounts of a customer by their first payment date. Sometimes the first account they open is never funded and thus has a date '1900-01-01' for "First_pay_date". I want to keep that row of info but do not want to include it in the rank.

Current outcome with code:

| CUST | ACCT | FIRST_PAY_DATE | RANK_BY_FIRST_PAY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JOHN H | JOHNH1 | 1900-01-01 | NULL |
| JOHN H | JOHNH2 | 2000-02-25 | 2 |
| JOHN H | JOHNH3 | 2001-03-21 | 3 |
| JOHN H | JOHNH4 | 2002-12-01 | 4 |

Desired Result:

| CUST | ACCT | FIRST_PAY_DATE | RANK_BY_FIRST_PAY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JOHN H | JOHNH1 | 1900-01-01 | 0 |
| JOHN H | JOHNH2 | 2000-02-25 | 1 |
| JOHN H | JOHNH3 | 2001-03-21 | 2 |
| JOHN H | JOHNH4 | 2002-12-01 | 3 |

```
SELECT
       cust,
       acct,
       first_pay_date,
       CASE
             WHEN first_pay_date <> '1900-01-01' THEN RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY cust
       ORDER BY
             first_pay_date)
       END rank_by_first_pay
FROM
       acct_table
ORDER BY
       first_pay_date ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something, `rank()... - 1` should return the result you want, no need for the `case` expression:

```
SELECT
       cust,
       acct,
       first_pay_date,
       RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY cust
       ORDER BY
             first_pay_date) - 1
       rank_by_first_pay
FROM
       acct_table
ORDER BY
       first_pay_date ASC
```

And depending on the behaviour you want in case of ties, you might want to use `dense_rank()` instead of `rank()`.

Comment: AHH, thought this was the simple answer. The statement subtracted 1 from all the ranks including those that funded their accounts even with the case statement (customer that does not have any account with 1900-01-01).

Comment: @B.Win it does produce the output you want though, doesn't it?

Comment: Only for customers with 1900-01-01. It doesn't work for customers who funded all accounts

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to push the '1900-01-01' to null value and use DENSE_RANK() as recommended above. The benefit is if an account doesn't have the initial 1900-01-01 data point it's not lost. The 1900-01-01 are also nicely placed at the end of the ranking - and if there's more than one instance you'll see them (instead of silently hiding the data error).

```
with sample_data as (
  select 'JOHN H'CUST ,'JOHNH1' ACCT,'1900-01-01'::date FIRST_PAY_DATE   
union select 'JOHN H'CUST,'JOHNH2' as ACCT,'2000-02-25' as FIRST_PAY_DATE   
union select 'JOHN H'CUST,'JOHNH3' as ACCT,'2001-03-21' as FIRST_PAY_DATE   
union select 'JOHN H'CUST,'JOHNH4' as ACCT,'2002-12-01' as FIRST_PAY_DATE   
union select 'JOBE' CUST,'JOBE1' ACCT,'2000-01-01' FIRST_PAY_DATE    
union select 'JOBE' CUST,'JOBE2' as ACCT,'2000-02-25' as FIRST_PAY_DATE 
union select 'JOBE' CUST,'JOBE3' as ACCT,'2001-03-21' as FIRST_PAY_DATE 
union select 'JOBE' CUST,'JOBE4' as ACCT,'2001-03-21' as FIRST_PAY_DATE )

select 
    CUST 
    ,ACCT
    ,REPLACE(FIRST_PAY_DATE,'1900-01-01','NULL') ADJUSTED_FIRST_PAY_DATE 
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CUST ORDER BY ADJUSTED_FIRST_PAY_DATE) RANKED_EX_1900
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CUST ORDER BY FIRST_PAY_DATE)-1 RANKED_MINUS_ONE
FROM
    SAMPLE_DATA
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your example output, your RANK function is 0 for the unwanted "1900" date, but what which leads to the simple `-1` answer.

So a more logical solution is to making an `ADJUISTED_FIRST_PAY` you can use [NULLIF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/nullif.html) and use the ORDER NULLS LAST, and then us an [IFF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/iff.html) to skip that VALUE

long form:

```
SELECT 
    cust 
    ,acct
    ,NULLIF(first_pay_date,'1900-01-01`) AS clean_date
    ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY cust ORDER BY clean_date NULLS LAST) AS ranked
    ,IFF(first_pay_date='1900-01-01`, NULL, ranked) AS answer
FROM
    sample_data
```

short form:

```
SELECT 
    cust 
    ,acct
    ,IFF(first_pay_date='1900-01-01`, 
        NULL, 
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY cust ORDER BY NULLIF(first_pay_date,'1900-01-01`) NULLS LAST)) AS answer
FROM
    sample_data
```

which can be pushed to zero like:

```
SELECT 
    cust 
    ,acct
    ,IFF(first_pay_date='1900-01-01`, 
        0, 
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY cust ORDER BY NULLIF(first_pay_date,'1900-01-01`) NULLS LAST)) AS answer
FROM
    sample_data
```

OR just partition on DATE being the value you want to ignore, and ignore the results, or force them to zero/null

```
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY cust, year(first_pay_date)=1900 ORDER BY first_pay_date)
```

and zero'ed out

```
SELECT 
    cust 
    ,acct
    ,year(first_pay_date)=1900, 
        0, 
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY cust, year(first_pay_date)=1900 ORDER BY first_pay_date)
    ) AS answer
FROM
    sample_data
```